# Google automatic typing

Tags: keyboard, voice-typing

How to turn off automatic Google typing when I turned on automatically and I've tried everything else just turn it off to get my keyboard back

`

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo1Zs.png) what you're talking about?

Comment: Yeah just appeared in I can't get my keyboard back for texting or anything and I've tried everything

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when that mic icon appears, you can easily dismiss it by pressing anywhere on the screen other than the mic window. You can also dismiss it by pressing on the back button on your phone.

Comment: Yes I've done all that to get it off my screen but I can't get the keyboard to come back up I went through all my settings and apps to make sure they're right and it's like a ghost screen

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?